# Is there an idiom that means "fight each other with the intent to hurt each other severely"?

Tags: idioms, idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means "fight each other with the intent to hurt each other severely"? I was thinking about "be at each other’s throats", but it seems that it's not used to mean that, rather the definition states:

> if two people are at each other’s throats, they are arguing in an
>   angry way
>
> As soon as politics comes up, they’ll be at each other’s throats.

Are there any good idioms that come to mind?

Comment: Do you mean physically or emotionally?

Comment: I mean physically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some possibilities include:

"Engaged/were locked in mortal combat."

"Fought (each other) to the death."

"dueled", "clashed"

Softer possibilities include "threw down" (which evokes the image of someone removing boxing gloves and restrictive clothing - "The gloves came off"), or softer still, they "had a fight".

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following idioms.

**To push one's buttons.** Meaning: to do things that create a very strong emotional reaction in one, especially anger, irritation, or exasperation:

> I hate Mary's new boyfriend, he's always trying to push my buttons, and he's doing a good job of it!

**To hit/strike/touch a nerve.** Meaning: to make someone feel angry, upset, embarrassed, etc.:

> Something she said to him must have hit/struck/touched a nerve. I've never seen him so angry.

So, the idioms above can all be used to describe hurting someone's feelings. However, they don't mean a fight per se. For example, if you say "they are pushing each other's buttons" or "They are touching a nerve," it doesn't necessarily meaning having a fight. But it means hurting, possibly during an argument:

> I hate to fight with her! She knows how to push my buttons/hit a nerve because her words hurt like a knife!

Comment: I meant physically hurt each other in a very severe way.

Comment: @blackbird Oh, I see. It wasn't clear enough. I thought you meant emotional hurting, not beating. Then I can only think of "beat the hell out of someone" - https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/beat+the+hell+out+of

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps

- They were **literally at each others' throats** (barehanded fighting only)
- Now they were **fighting for real**.  George saw the glint of the knife and grabbed the first thing he touched: a crowbar.